# How to use angular async binding

Tags: angular, rxjs5

I want to do something like 
`<span *ngIf="admins.includes(name) | async">` where `admins` is defined in the component class as `admins:Observable<string[]>`
I know this does not work but is possible to achieve this in any way?

Thanks so much for help!

Comment: What is your actual goal? To imply show the span if `name` exists in the admin list - yeah?

Comment: Yes - that is correct. It admins was a simple list instead of observable I would do that `<span *ngIf="admins.includes(name)>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The async pipe needs to be on the observable itself like below.

```
<span *ngIf="(admins | async)?.includes(name)">
```